# Why display:none is not working as expected in ie7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, hide

This is the fiddle for my question http://jsfiddle.net/v2q4e/show/ and

find below the html that I have :

```
<div class="c-panel">
    <div class="c-panel-section-body">
        <div class="c-data-entry">
            <span id="span1" class="c-hide c-label">
                <label id="lbl1">Account</label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm concerned about the span#span1, I expect it to be hidden. In all browsers except native IE7, it is hidden (not shown), even in IE8's compatibility mode plus IE8's IE7 mode, it shows hidden.

Find below how all other browsers find which rule gets applied for that span : [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn3sh.png)

Whereas in IE7, I found the following orer in which the rules were applied :

```
Case 1: When div c-data-entry after div.panel-section-body is not present, the label Account appears :
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 /* Rule 629 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
 DIV.c-panel .c-hide {  DISPLAY: none} 

 /* Rule 630 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
 DIV.c-panel-section-body .c-hide { DISPLAY: none} 

 /* Rule 81 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-ie67.css */ 
 .ie7 SPAN.c-label {    ZOOM: 1} 

 /* Rule 627 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
 .c-hide {  DISPLAY: none}


Case 2: When div c-data-entry after div.panel-section-body is present, the label Account appears :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Rule 319 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
.c-data-entry SPAN.c-label {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    DISPLAY: block;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
    PADDING-TOP: 8px
} 

/* Rule 629 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */
 DIV.c-panel .c-hide {  DISPLAY: none} 

/* Rule 630 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
DIV.c-panel-section-body .c-hide {  DISPLAY: none} 

/* Rule 81 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-ie67.css */ 
.ie7 SPAN.c-label { ZOOM: 1} 

/* Rule 627 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
.c-hide {   DISPLAY: none}


Case 3: When div.c-data-entry after div.panel-section-body is not present, but added new “rule like 630”  below:
-------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Rule 630 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
DIV.c-panel SPAN.c-hide {   DISPLAY: none} 

/* Rule 319 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */
 .c-data-entry SPAN.c-label {   PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-LEFT: 0px;  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;  PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;    PADDING-TOP: 8px} 

 /* Rule 629 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
 DIV.c-panel .c-hide {  DISPLAY: none} 

 /* Rule 631 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
 DIV.c-panel-section-body .c-hide { DISPLAY: none} 

 /* Rule 81 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-ie67.css */ 
 .ie7 SPAN.c-label {    ZOOM: 1} 

 /* Rule 627 of http://localhost:8030/be/1.1/css/be-core.css */ 
 .c-hide {  DISPLAY: none}
```

I took this order using the "Applied styles" on right clicking the span tag in native IE7's developer tools.

My question is : I want the span#span1 to be hidden (as it happens in other browsers) without the need to add the new rule as shown in the 3rd case.

Can anybody explain why IE7 would apply Rule 319 which is well on the top in the same file as compared to Rule 629 or Rule 631 ?

Am I missing some basic knowledge here ? Please enlighten.

Comment: Is the question not clear ? Anybody ? any ideas ? Any comments ?